# Why Start menu shortcut is not removed after uninstallation?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

When i installed .msi file, I am getting generated shortcuts on start menu and desktop, but when i am uninstalling the desktop shortcut getting removed but start menu. My code is bellow. Please help me to solve my problem. I have spent almost 1 day behind this.

```
<Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
   <Directory Id="ProgramMenuSubfolder" Name="Kiosk">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcuts" Guid="12345678-1234-1234-1234-333333333333">
         <Shortcut Id="ApplicationShortcut1" Name="Kiosk" Description="Solusoft Product" Target="[INSTALLDIR]AMP\1.0.0.0\mpkiosk.exe" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"/>
         <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Kiosk" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
         <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationShortcut1" On="uninstall"/>
      </Component>
   </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, on the component, I had GUID="*" and the shorcuts weren't removed.

I used a hardcoded GUID like: Guid="cc509cb7-c1a1-46cf-8c62-7cbb0017783c" and the shortcuts were removed.

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

You have a mistake in your code.

Instead of:

```
<RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationShortcut1" On="uninstall"/>
```

Use:

```
<RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuSubfolder" On="uninstall"/>
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was trying different options, and had a commented out section that had the same GUID. Changing it to a different GUID, even though the other was commented out, worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is the code below that i'm using in my project. Hope, it will helps. I think you could use **'RemoveFile'** instead **'RemoveFolder'** and don't forget to put **'Name'** attribute inside.

```
            <RegistryKey Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall" Root="HKCU"
                         Key="Software\$(var.ManufacturerEng)\$(var.ProductName)\$(var.ApplicationName)">
                <RegistryValue Name="ShortcutService"
                               Type="integer" Value="1"
                               KeyPath="yes">
                </RegistryValue>
            </RegistryKey>
            <Shortcut Advertise="no" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder"
                      Name="ServiceCC"
                      Target="[INSTALLLOCATION]Service.exe"
                      Id="SHORTCUT_serv"
                      WorkingDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION">
            </Shortcut>
            <RemoveFile Id="remove_serviceshort" Name="ServiceCC" On="uninstall"/>
            <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        </Component>
```

Comment: This did it for me. To point it out even more: "Name" is the connecting declaration between Shortcut and RemoveFile both using the value "ServiceCC".

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a copy paste error.  I was using the same Guid for the component as another product I had created a shortcut in that folder for.  Hence on uninstall the removal of the icon failed